# First Attempt at Object-Oriented Programming: Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, game, tic-tac-toe

Began learning python about 3 months ago and this was my first OOP. I was hoping to get constructive feedback! My own thoughts after writing it were that there had to be a better way to: 1) generate the game board 2) code the logic for determining the winner via horizontal, vertical, or diagonal.

```py
class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.positions = [None, ]
        for x in range(1,10):
            self.positions.append(str(x))

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.positions[x]

    def generate_board(self):
        for x in range(2):
            if x == 0:
                print(self.positions[1].center(3,'_') + '|' + self.positions[2].center(3,'_') + '|' + self.positions[3].center(3,'_'))
            else:
                print(self.positions[4].center(3,'_') + '|' + self.positions[5].center(3,'_') + '|' + self.positions[6].center(3,'_'))

        print(self.positions[7].center(3) + '|' + self.positions[8].center(3) + '|' + self.positions[9].center(3))

class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, piece):
        self.name = name
        self.piece = piece

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        name1 = input('p1 name: ')
        name2 = input('p2 name: ')
        p1_piece = input('Pick your piece player 1: (Type X or O) ')
        if p1_piece != 'X' or p1_piece != 'O':
            p1_piece = input('Player 1 did not pick a valid piece: (Type X or O) ')
        if p1_piece == 'X':
            p2_piece = 'O'
        else:
            p2_piece = 'X'
        self.p1 = Player(name1, p1_piece)
        self.p2 = Player(name2, p2_piece)
        self.positions = Board()
        self.win = False
        self.winner = ''

    def play_game(self):
        tie_count = 0
        while self.win == False:

            #generating board
            print('\n')
            print('Here is the board: ')
            Board.generate_board(self)

            #player 1's turn. Checking for win or tie in between turns.
            print('\n' + "Player 1's turn. Type the position where you would like to place your piece")
            position = input()
            if position in self.positions.positions:
                self.positions.positions[int(position)] = self.p1.piece
                print('\n')
                print('Here is the board: ')
                Board.generate_board(self)
            Game.game_check(self)
            if self.win == True:
                break

            #checking to see if the game is a tie. 
            for i in range(1,10):
                if str(i) not in self.positions:
                    tie_count += 1
            if tie_count == 9:
                self.winner += "It's a tie! Nobody"
                self.win = True
            else:
                tie_count = 0
            if self.win == True:
                break

            print('\n' + "Player 2's turn. Type the position where you would like to place your piece")
            position = input()
            if position in self.positions.positions:
                self.positions.positions[int(position)] = self.p2.piece
                print('\n')
                print('Here is the board: ')
                Board.generate_board(self)
            Game.game_check(self)
            if self.win == True:
                break

        print('\n')
        print('The game is over! {} wins!'.format(self.winner))

    def game_check(self):
        #establishing counters for later use
        p1_bucket = 0
        p2_bucket = 0

        #below code counts horizontal wins
        for i in range(1,10,3):
                if self.positions.positions[i:i+3].count(self.p1.piece) == 3:
                    self.win = True
                    self.winner += self.p1.name
                elif self.positions.positions[i:i+3].count(self.p2.piece) == 3:
                    self.win = True
                    self.winner += self.p2.name

        #below code counts vertical wins
        for x in range(1,4):
            #nested for loop accomplishes sliding pattern for vertical combos (i.e. 1,4,7 then 2,5,8 etc.)
            for y in range(x,x+7,3):
                if self.positions.positions[y] == self.p1.piece:
                    p1_bucket += 1
                elif self.positions.positions[y] == self.p2.piece:
                    p2_bucket += 1
            if p1_bucket == 3:  
                self.win = True
                self.winner += self.p1.name
                break
            elif p2_bucket == 3:
                self.win = True
                self.winner += self.p2.name
                break
            else:
                p1_bucket = 0
                p2_bucket = 0

        #below code counts diagonal wins
        for x in range(1,10,4):
            if self.positions.positions[x] == self.p1.piece:
                p1_bucket += 1
            elif self.positions.positions[x] == self.p2.piece:
                p2_bucket += 1
        if p1_bucket == 3:  
            self.win = True
            self.winner += self.p1.name
        elif p2_bucket == 3:
            self.win = True
            self.winner += self.p2.name
        else:
            p1_bucket = 0
            p2_bucket = 0

        for x in range(3,8,2):
            if self.positions.positions[x] == self.p1.piece:
                p1_bucket += 1
            elif self.positions.positions[x] == self.p2.piece:
                p2_bucket += 1
        if p1_bucket == 3:  
            self.win = True
            self.winner += self.p1.name
        elif p2_bucket == 3:
            self.win = True
            self.winner += self.p2.name
        else:
            p1_bucket = 0
            p2_bucket = 0

game1 = Game()
game1.play_game()
```